# Аргументы явно специализированной шаблонной функции

Tags: c++, c, шаблоны-с++

Я заинтересовался вопросом явной специализации шаблона функции. Например нужна функция обменом значений переданных аргументов. Если простые типы, структуры и классы, то все пойдет под шаблон - передаю в качестве фактических параметров ссылки на обменяемые объекты и меняю их. Но, если массив или С-строка, то так не пойдет и я решил использовать явную спецификацию(знаю, что можно перегрузку, но хочу со всеми путями разобраться) и передавать указатель на массив, что бы обменять их содержимое. Вот так. Но так не работает, почему?
Вот пример прототипов:

```
template <typename T> void Exchanging(T&, T&); //template

template <> void Exchanging <int*> (int*, int*); //specialization
```

Возможно есть правила типизации аргументов явно специализированной функции по отношению к шаблонной?

Comment: У вас спецификация отличается. В шаблоне вы принимаете `T&` где **T** выводится как **int***, а в спецификации просто `T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вы же сказали, что передавать можно только ссылки. Так и специализируйте соответственно:

```
template <> void Exchanging (int*&, int*&)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: То есть, если в шаблоне тип ссылка, то и в спецификации должна быть ссылка? Нельзя например в шаблоне тип - указатель, а в спецификации простой тип (значение)? Должно быть соответствие типов между шаблоном и спецификацией?

Comment: Да, вы объявили Exchanging,  как  шаблон функции, которая принимает две ссылки  любого типа и ничего не возвращает. Специализация функции должна выражать то же, только уже для конкретного типа. В ответе  специализирован вариант с`int*`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Здесь "спасибо за ответ" выражается в нажатии птички слева от него...